# AWS Amplify DataStore filtering not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, datastore, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS Amplify framework, i have a list of products, each product contains a price, when i run :

`DataStore.query(Product)`

to get all the products it works fine, but when i run the query below to get the products with price greater than 10 :

`DataStore.query(Product, c => c.price.gt(10));`

i got an error `TypeError: c.price.gt is not a function` !

this is how it described in [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/data-access/q/platform/js/#predicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way below worked perfectly !

`DataStore.query(Product, (c) => c.price('gt', 10))`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/examples/q/platform/js/):

```
const posts = await DataStore.query(Product, (c) => c. price.gt(10));
```

This works for me!